# Setting gross price in Prestashop via API

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, erp

Good morning.

I'm writing a live price integration ERP -> Prestashop v1.6. ERP has prices that include tax, but Prestashop needs net prices in API. Could I change it gross prices?

It is possible to set gross price via Admin Panel, but it seams to me they are calculated in JS: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/js/admin/price.js

I need to do it inside Prestashop, because ERP is unchangeable. What is the best approach to handle this? Maybe there is some kind of extension that could help? For now my best shot is to create separate API method for setting gross price and translate JS logic to PHP code.

Comment: You have to give the NET price to PrestaShop, because it have a 'complex' tax calculation method. If you calculate the net price before send via API?

Comment: I would like to keep the Presta's logic implementation inside the Presta.

Comment: You are referring to a simple JS script that calculate the net price based on the tax rules applied to that product. Notice that I'm not say tax ratio, but tax rules that's different for PS.
So pick the JS code and 'convert' in PHP I suppose :)